# Fit image to paragraph width

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Let's say I have the following css

```
.text{
    position:absolute;
    padding: 0 25px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.6);
}
```

And following html

```
<div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-md-6">
        <div class = "text">
            <h3>Title 1</h3>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
            </p>
        </div>
        <img src = "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/51/d6/e3/51d6e3dcccd3bdac300202a5a3e99de0--pretty-cats-beautiful-cats.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class = "col-md-6">
        <div class = "text">
            <h3>Title 2</h3>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
            </p>
        </div>
        <img src = "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/51/d6/e3/51d6e3dcccd3bdac300202a5a3e99de0--pretty-cats-beautiful-cats.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

How would I get the image to shrink or stretch to fit the width of the whole paragraph, and the height to remain centered on the image.

As an example
If image was 600 x 600 and paragraph took 300 x 150 pixels then the image would shrink down to 300 x 300 and the area that would be displayed would be starting at position (0, 50) and would be size of (300, 150).

I know that I haven't provided any example of what I tried, but if you can at least point me in right direction I would be ever so grateful.

Comment: can you use background images instead of img elements?

Comment: why `position:absolute;` on text ? and why not simply make the image 100% width ?

Comment: @RobertWade yes I am content with using background images instead of img elements. I simply suck so I have no proper knowledge of how to use images, background image would be much better however

Comment: Look into `background-size:cover` then.  I think you'll find it can do what yo want. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [background-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) with url of your image and [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) set as "cover".
I think that ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t63jme8r/)) should be what you are looking for:

```
.background-img-cat {
  background-image:url('https://i.pinimg.com/736x/51/d6/e3/51d6e3dcccd3bdac300202a5a3e99de0--pretty-cats-beautiful-cats.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
}


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 background-img-cat">
        <div class="text">
            <h3>Title 1</h3>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 background-img-cat">
        <div class="text">
            <h3>Title 2</h3>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
                Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
                Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You got the correct answer, if you do not mind, please add center to the background, because otherwise it shows the top of the image but I wanted the center. Overall however thank you very much for the answer, it is exactly what I wanted!

Comment: You can get center of the image with following : background-position: center